# How to checkout remote branch with git clone --depth 1?

Tags: git

I downloaded last revision of a big repository, where I need to get a latest revision of one branch so that I can test it.

How do I do that?

When I did `git clone --depth 1 url` I got last revision of master and the branch doesn't seem to exist?

```
petanb@petrbena:~/Documents/mh$ git checkout flaggedrevs
error: pathspec 'flaggedrevs' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`git clone --depth 1` [implicitly carries](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) a `--single-branch` option, which defaults to the primary branch, which is `origin/master` by default.

If you want to clone a different branch, tell git which one you want to clone.

`git clone --depth 1  --branch <branch> url`

Answer (score 24):

You can directly fetch anything you want:

```
git fetch --depth 1 origin flaggedrevs:flaggedrevs  #  `origin` can be a URL too
```

That will create a normal (albeit shallow) branch from what you fetched.  To get more conventional results, `git fetch --depth 1 origin flaggedrevs:refs/remotes/origin/flaggedrevs`. "copy origin's flaggedrevs to my refs/remotes/origin/flaggedrevs".

Haul up .git/config and look at it, or say `git config --get-regexp fetch`.  If you don't explicitly tell it what to fetch, that's what it fetches.